# Convert int bytestream to a float bytestream

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have a 32-bit integer. The bit stream is actually a bit stream for a 32-bit float (IEEE 754). I tried converting it with:

```
unpack('f', $input);
```

This generates a float, but it seems it is not the right number

For example, if I pass in 1, I should be coming out with 1.4012984e-45, according to the [IEEE754 converter](http://www.ajdesigner.com/fl_ieee_754_word/ieee_32_bit_word.php),
but I am coming with 2.5638762224389E-9

Thanks a lot for any help/advice.

Comment: Usenet to the rescue: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/PHP/alt.php/2004-11/0375.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing things:

```
<?php
$s = "\x01\x00\x00\x00";
$t = "0001"; //same as "\x30\x30\x30\x31"
var_dump(unpack('f', $s));
var_dump(unpack('f', $t));
```

gives

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  float(1.4012984643248E-45)
}
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  float(2.5638762224389E-9)
}
```

According to the manual, these results are not guaranteed (the "f" modifier in `unpack` will depend on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system). But one thing is a byte stream which has actually those values and other thing is to have a byte stream which happens to translate to "0001" when the ASCII charset is considered.

Comment: I understand they are not the same. However, the $input that I pass in is not a string, but a number. Am I wrong in assuming that unpack('f', 1) and unpack('f', '\x01\x00\x00\x00') are equivalent? (on a little endian system, which is where this code will be run (x86/x64))

Comment: @Goro unpack expects a string, so it converts the number you pass it into a string. Type conversion rules in PHP make int(1) => string "1".

Comment: @Goro You can use a combination of pack and unpack. This will work regardless of the endianness of the system: `unpack('f', pack('L', 1)))`